# How to Remove Configurable Product Variation / Not required Or Unset Variation?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configurable-product

I want to remove Configurable Product Variation, I want custom will click on add to cart without selecting options. Now if i'll click on add to cart then getting this error.

You need to choose options for your item.

So How to I can do that ? How Can I make unrequired those fields ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A configurable product requires that the attribute(s) that you used to create configurations are selected.
For example, if you create an configurable product T100 with configuration attributes color and size, you will always have to select a color and a size. The configurable product doesn't have inventory and can't be purchased directly.